# Cygwin script access to COM port denied

Tags: serial-port

I get 'access denied' when using a shell script in cygwin.
Using stty > /dev/ttyS6 (for COM6).

Yet python scipts work fine, no access problem.

Have checked that I am i dialup group in cygwin.
Checked permissions on /dev/ttyS5

Can't find /etc/groups to check dialup is there.
Can't see if I am in dialup.

Comment: Wrong site for this type of question. Take the tour and/or read the help pages. Post at Superuser.com.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever figure it out? I have a program that needs stty to configure the serial port and uses read() and printf() to talk to a device over serial all from pure bash. Works fine in linux, freebsd, macos.
I have another program that's plain c, and IT compiles and works fine in the same cygwin or msys2 session. No problems accessing and configuring the tty. Same literal session at the same time, same hardware, user etc.

Comment: Actually it's weirder than that...
I have an stty command that works at the interactive prompt, but fails when run from within a bash script.

`bkw@win10pro_bkw ~` 
`$ stty -F /dev/ttyS5 19200 pass8 clocal -echo time 1 min 1 crtscts -ixon -ixoff ;echo $?`
`0`

/usr/local/bin/pdd has
`#!/usr/bin/env bash`
`set -x`
`...`

`bkw@win10pro_bkw ~`
`$ pdd ttyS5`
`...`
`+ stty -F /dev/ttyS5 19200 pass8 clocal -echo time 1 min 1 crtscts -ixon -ixoff`
`stty: /dev/ttyS5: Permission denied`
`+ return 1`
`...`